Powershell script for setting two Windows registry values using Set-ItemProperty does not work
In the below mentioned Powershell script, the registry key for "NoAutoUpdate" never works. But, In the same script, if I add the "NoAutoUpdate" registry addition logic after AppLocker logic, it works 80% of the time.
I am neither able to find the root cause nor able to make it work consistently. What do you think I am missing?
try {

    $filesToCopy = ""
    
    foreach ($file in $filesToCopy) {
        Copy-Item -Path $file.Source -Destination $file.Destination -Recurse -Force
    }

    #AppLocker
    $registryPath = "Registry::HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\AppIDSvc"   # This path is to find Application Identity service
    $name = "Start"
    $value = "2"
    $filename = "\Rules.xml"   
    $CertName = "\x.cer"
    $invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
    $directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
    $Certpath = $directorypath + $CertName  
    $filepath = $directorypath + $filename    

    # Add Registry key to stop Windows Auto Updates
    $regPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU"
    try {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $regPath -Name NoAutoUpdate -Value 1 -Type DWord -Force
        Write-Output "NoAutoUpdate registry key created successfully."
    } catch {
        Write-Output "Failed to create NoAutoUpdate registry key: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }

    # Add certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store
    Set-Location -Path cert:\LocalMachine\Root   
    Import-Certificate -Filepath $Certpath   

    Write-Host "AppLocker enabled and rules created successfully." 
     
    # Check if the Application Identity service is running
    $serviceStatus = Get-Service -Name "AppIDSvc"
    if ($serviceStatus.Status -eq 'Running') {
        Write-Host "Application Identity service is running already."
    } else {
        # Set the Application Identity service to start automatically
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value
        Write-Host "Application Identity service is starting. Please wait until the system reboots." 
        # Restart the computer
        shutdown /r  
    }
} 
catch {   
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    return $false
} 
finally {  
    # Any cleanup code can go here if necessary
}

Output:
NoAutoUpdate registry key created successfully.
AppLocker enabled and rules created successfully.
Application Identity service is starting. Please wait until the system reboots.


Can you share the output (including any error messages)?

$regPath is never set, possibly a typo? Also you don't seem to do actually anything in the #AppLocker section. On a side note: you can Import-Certificate without using Set-Location by using -CertStoreLocation parameter. You can set service startup using the Set-Service function. Restart-Computer is more idiomatic than shutdown in Powershell. All of this can be done better with Group Policy.

@MathiasR.Jessen Added the powershell output.

@Charlieface  Apologies for the typo. I've updated the script and ran it to get the output too.
